# How to change center tab bar button colour in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibutton, uinavigationitem

I want the middle button in my `UITabBarController` to have a different colour to the others, like Instagram for example. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of colour you should set every `tabBarItem` image differently for each one (If you want it just like instagram)

**Here is an example for one:**

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [yourTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2]; //set objectAtIndex you want (For Instagram its 2)

UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected-imagename"]; //set unselected image
UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected-imagename"]; //set selected image

[tabBarItem setImage: [unselectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[tabBarItem setSelectedImage: selectedImage];
```

Hope this helps :)

Cheers

Comment: This only changes the picture of the button, I want the rectangular shaped button that has the picture inside it to have different colour..

Comment: I you want the rectangular shape button then just create a rectangular shape image...